# C++ ¿ Como Ordenar un Array Alfabeticamente?

Tags: c++, array

Holas buenas!

Entiendo que en el código de abajo se me debe de estar pasando algo a la hora de almacenar el mayor de las dos variables que comparo.... Pero no consigo realizar el orden alfabético e imprimirlo por pantalla

Tendría que desarrollar un programa que pida 10 palabras por consola y almacenarlas en un array. Después se pide que sacar por pantalla las 10 palabras ordenadas alfabéticamente. Como condiciones no se puede utilizar Sort. Y como pista el uso del bucle IF.

Ahora mismo solo consigo el código de abajo, pero no que almacene e imprima por pantalla de forma Alfabética

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    
    int num=3;
    string palabras[num];
    string aux1;
    
    for(int i=0;i<num;i++){

    cout<<"Introduce una palabra: "<<endl;
    cin>>palabras[i];

    }

    for(int i=0;i<num;i++){

        for(int j=i+1;j<num;j++){

            if(palabras[i]>palabras[j]){ // Antonio, Bobo, Carlos 1>2

                aux1=palabras[j]; //almaceno 2
                palabras[i]=palabras[j]; // cambio el valor a J ahora es 1
                aux1=palabras[i]; // cambio el valor a i ahora es 2

                }

            }
        for(int i=0;i<num;i++){
        cout<<palabras[i]<<endl;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Y cual es el problema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Casi lo tienes, solo hay un pequeño error a la hora de intercambiar tus arreglos en la parte de los for anidados.

Checa con este:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    
    int num=3;
    string palabras[num];
    string aux1;
    
    for(int i=0;i<num;i++){
    cout<<"Introduce una palabra: "<<endl;
    cin>>palabras[i];
    }

    cout << endl;

    for(int i=0;i<num;i++){
        for(int j=i+1;j<num;j++){
            if(palabras[i]>palabras[j]){ 

                aux1 = palabras[j]; 
                palabras[j] = palabras[i]; 
                palabras[i] = aux1; 
            }
        }
    }
    cout << endl;
    for(int i=0;i<num;i++){
        cout<<palabras[i]<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hola, yo por ejemplo tengo palabras que tienen mayuscula, y me sucede que me pone la palabra con mayuscula al principio y luego las que son todas con minuscula ordenadas alfabeticamente. Como haria para que tambien me tome correctamente las que tienen mayusculas??